# Increase Precision in Numerical Integration

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I need to generate a table of Chebyshev expansion coefficients of trigonometric functions (in this case Cos[2 Pi t] to very high accuracy. Code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

m = 4;

f[t] = Cos[2 Pi t];
Tn[t] = ChebyshevT[j, 2*t - 1];
wt[t] = 1/Sqrt[t - t^2];    

p = Table[
   NIntegrate[f[t]*Tn[t]*wt[t], {t, 0, 1}]/(Pi/2.0), {j, 0, m - 1}];
p[[1]] = p[[1]]/2;

p
```

Where f[t] is the trigonometric function, Tn[t], is the shifted Chebyshev polynomial, w[t] is the weight function. How can I increase the precision of this numerical integration?

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I've read dozens of past questions dealing with $MinPrecision, $MinAccuracy, PrecisionGoal, WorkingPrecision, etc. and I've been unable to increase the precision. I'm stuck at machine precision still!

Comment: you do know dividing by `2.0`converts the result to machine precision regardless of what `NIntegrate` does..  `WorkingPrecision -> 20 , PrecisionGoal -> 20` should do what you want if you make that an integer `2`

Comment: @george2079 I did not know that, but now I do. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to point out that Mathematica can do the calculation symbolically (ie, infinite precision) for $0\leq m\leq 6$ (and possibly higher). So you could just calculate the symbolic results and then apply `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are converted to `MachinePrecision` because you divide by the machine precision number `Pi/2.0`.  You can get exact solutions with `Integrate` and use `N`.  This will be more accurate than `NIntegrate`.

```
Block[{m = 4},
 p = Table[
    Integrate[f[t]*Tn[t]*wt[t], {t, 0, 1}]/(Pi/2), {j, 0, m - 1}];
 ]
p[[1]] = p[[1]]/2;

p
(*
  {-BesselJ[0, π],
   0,
   2 BesselJ[2, π],
   0}
*)

N[p, 20]
(*
  {0.30424217764409386420,
   0,
   0.97086786526301821941,
   0}
*)
```